# If else statement in java (Android)

Tags: java, android, if-statement, notifications, firebase

can anyone help me on how to create an if else statement in android java. ? i am doing a chat app using firebase ,and  i got stock because of the notification. now i would like to increase the number of messages every time i chat you. Like in example below ,let say i am john".

```
John: hi jacki
Jacki: hello
```

therefore:
if i will check my firebase dashboard the numMessage is counted as 1 . because i did chat jacki once in our conversation.

Heres my code/

```
package com.example.mypc.thisissample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.firebase.client.Firebase;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private EditText editText;
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        final Firebase firebase = new Firebase("https://example.firebaseio.com/");


        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        listView.setAdapter(new MessageAdapter(this, Message.class, R.layout.fragment_message, firebase.child("chat")));

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Message message = new Message();

                message.setMessage(editText.getText().toString());
                message.setAuthor("Name");

                firebase.child("chat").push().setValue(message);

                editText.setText("");



            }
        });
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get what you really need, please explain a little better. But if you are asking for if/else statement in java try to read some java cookbook first!

Anyway

```
if(statement) {
} else {
}
```

---

### Edit One:

First read de numCount from the firebase and store it on a localVariable

https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html

Then every time someone press the send button push the number to the firebase.

https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html

Here you have an example of an increment

```
final Firebase upvoteref = new Firebase("https://shareurday.firebaseio.com/Message/"+msg_id+"/upvotes"); 

        upvoteref.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
            @Override
            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(final MutableData currentData) {
                if (currentData.getValue() == null) {
                    currentData.setValue(1);
                } else {
                    currentData.setValue((Long) currentData.getValue() + 1);
                }
                return Transaction.success(currentData);
            }

            public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, boolean committed, DataSnapshot currentData) {
                if (firebaseError != null) {
                    System.out.println("Firebase counter increment failed.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Firebase counter increment succeeded.");
                }
            }
        });
```

Hope it helps

Comment: i want to put an if statement wherein the number of messages will count ++ everytime i send a message . like in the example given ,if i will chat you , it will increase the variable numMessage it depends on how many times did i chat you.

Comment: it's complicated because i am using firebase . anyway

Comment: Confusing though. is the sample will count++ the numMessages everytime i send you a message? :)?